# ProtoBuf.Net - Use Proto as TypeFormatter

Tags: .net, protobuf-net

Im POC'ing using ProtoBuf.Net as NetDataContractSerializer(or BinarySerializer),
I have posted the code here [code](http://pasteit.com/17275).
It's trial and error, and still doesn't work with List, Dictionary etc.
It looks im going in the wrong direction,
Is it feasible ?

your feedback will be appreciated.

Comment: Is the full set of candidate root types known in advance? Or is your intention to serialize completely unknown types?

Comment: known in advance, the types are known on both sides the serializing and the deserializing

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Protobuf.net, and I did it by marking my classes like this:

```
  namespace music
  {
      [ProtoContract]
      public class Album
      {
          [ProtoMember(1)]
          public string Name { get; set; }

          [ProtoMember(2)]
         public List<string> TrackList { get; set; }
      }
  }
```

This works for Dictionaries and lists too.

The same numbering conventions apply to the attributes as to using the .proto message files, but you can include properties on base classes like this:

```
[ProtoContract]
[ProtoInclude(10, typeof(TypeInheritingFromPerson))]
[ProtoInclude(11, typeof(AnotherTypeInheritingFromPerson))]
public abstract class Person
{
    [DataMember]
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
 ...
```

and then using this line of code to serialize:

```
  MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
  ProtoBuf.Serializer.Serialize<Album>(stream, album);
```

You can of course use filestream instead of memory stream :)

If you are using WCF you can swap the DataContractSerializer for the Protobuf serializer directly in the config file like this (as copy pasted from the protobuf.net documentation), so you don't need to manually call any serialization code:

Add the following to the server and client app.config in the system.serviceModel section:

```
           <behaviors>
           <endpointBehaviors>
             <behavior name="ProtoBufBehaviorConfig">
               <ProtoBufSerialization/>
             </behavior>
           </endpointBehaviors>
         </behaviors>
         <extensions>
           <behaviorExtensions>
             <add name="ProtoBufSerialization" type="ProtoBuf.ServiceModel.ProtoBehaviorExtension, protobuf-net, Version=1.0.0.255, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=257b51d87d2e4d67"/>
           </behaviorExtensions>
         </extensions>
```

Configure your endpoints to have a behaviorConfiguration as follows:

```
         <service name="TK.Framework.Samples.ServiceModel.Contract.SampleService">
           <endpoint address="http://myhost:9003/SampleService" binding="basicHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="ProtoBufBehaviorConfig"
            bindingConfiguration="basicHttpBindingConfig" name="basicHttpProtoBuf" contract="ISampleServiceContract" />
         </service>
         <client>
             <endpoint address="http://myhost:9003/SampleService" binding="basicHttpBinding"
                 bindingConfiguration="basicHttpBindingConfig" contract="ISampleServiceContract"
                 name="BasicHttpProtoBufEndpoint" behaviorConfiguration="ProtoBufBehaviorConfig"/>
          </client>
```

I hope this is helpful for you, but let me know if you have any questions, or anything is unclear :)

Comment: thanks for replying, Im using Protobuf.NetV2 and using run time registration (code attached).I might be missing something, since im doing a recursion on all members and their members to register all needed object in graph.When adding List<> or Dictionary i get cannot serialize jagged/nested arrays which are List/Dictionary members.I guess im missing what Protobuf is using to serialize List/Dictionary, since obviously its members are not marked with Proto Attributes.

Comment: What does your data / class structure look like? Are you using types that you are unable to decorate with the protobuf attributes?

Comment: hmm... did you look at what was available in the ProtoBuf.Meta namespace?

Comment: I can decorate my types with attributes, but im reluctant since i would like to keep my domain entities clean of serialization attributes(except serializable).V2 enables adding them to modal at run time so i figured the behavior is symmetric to the decorative approach.I used this namespace as you could see in code linked, are you referring to some feature in particular ?

Comment: I was wondering if this might be something strange to do with the complexity of having lists inside a dictionary, so I did up a little sample to test it (using the protobuf attributes on the classes). Lo and behold I am also seeing null on the other side :\ I guess it makes sense, because there is not enough information about the lists to create a .proto message. I'm also PoCing this at the moment, so if I find a way around it I will post it :)

Comment: I tested with attributes and it works(Just added to the test ProtoContract and ProtoMembers), Still shouldn't it be symmetric with the run time registration?